Characterization of $T_2$ spaces via Filters and Nets

Given $(X, \mathcal{T})$ a topological space, denote $\mathcal{R}(X)$ and $\mathcal{F}(X)$ the sets of nets and filters of $X$ respectively. The following are equivalent: 
$(1)$ $X$ is $T_2$ 
$(2)$ For every $S \in \mathcal{R}(X) : |\lim S| \leq 1$ 
$(3)$ For every $\mathcal{F} \in \mathcal{F}(X) : |\lim \mathcal{F}| \leq 1$ 
$(4)$ For every $S \in \mathcal{R}(X)$ and every $x \in X$, if $S \rightarrow x$ then ${\rm agl} \,S = \{x\}$ 
$(5)$ For every $\mathcal{F} \in \mathcal{F}(X)$ and every $x \in X$, if $\mathcal{F} \rightarrow x$ then ${\rm agl} \, \mathcal{F} = \{x\}$

This appears on my General topology book without proof, so I want to know if which I write is fine.
$(1) \implies (5)$ Let $\mathcal{F} \in \mathcal{F}(X)$ and $x \in X$ such that $\mathcal{F} \rightarrow x$ . It is well known on Filters Theory that $\lim \mathcal{F} \subseteq {\rm agl} \, \mathcal{F}$, so $x \in {\rm agl} \, \mathcal{F}$ .
Now, let $y \in X \setminus \{x\}$. Since $X$ is $T_2$, there is $V \in \varepsilon (x)$ and $W \in \varepsilon (y)$ such that $V \cap W = \emptyset$ . By $\mathcal {F} \rightarrow x$ we deduce that $V \in \mathcal{F}$ and by $V \cap W = \emptyset$ it has that $y \notin \overline {V}$ . Finally, because of ${\rm agl} \, \mathcal{F} = \bigcap_{F \in \mathcal{F}} \overline{F}$ it follows that $y \notin {\rm agl} \, \mathcal{F}$ and then ${\rm agl} \, \mathcal{F} = \{x\}$ .
The implications $(5) \implies (4), (4) \implies (3)$ and $(3) \implies (2)$ are trivial since for every net there is a filter such that they have the same $\lim$ and ${\rm agl}$ and vice versa and that $\lim \subseteq {\rm agl}$ for both filters and nets.
$(2) \implies (1)$ By contraposition, suppose that $X$ is not $T_2$ . There is $x, y \in X, x \neq y$ such that every pair of neighbourhoods $(V, W) \in \varepsilon (x) \times \varepsilon (y)$ satisfies $V \cap W \neq \emptyset$ .
Define $\mathcal{B} = \{ V \cap W : (V, W) \in \varepsilon (x) \times \varepsilon (y) \}$ . It is clear that $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{B}$ and that $\mathcal{B} \neq \emptyset$ because $X \in \mathcal{B}$ . Given $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $B_1 \cap B_2 \neq \emptyset$, for $k\in \{1,2\}$ there are $V_k \in \varepsilon(x)$ and $W_k \in \varepsilon(y)$ such that $B_k = V_k \cap W_k$ . Then $B_1 \cap B_2 = (V_1 \cap W_1) \cap (V_2 \cap W_2) = (V_1 \cap V_2) \cap (W_1 \cap W_2) \in \mathcal{B}$, so $\mathcal{B}$ is a filter base.
Denote by $\mathcal{F}$ the filter generated by $\mathcal{B}$ and $S$ the net generated by $\mathcal{F}$ . For every $(V,W) \in \varepsilon(x) \times \varepsilon(y)$ it has that $V \cap W \subseteq V \implies V \in \mathcal{F}$ and $V \cap W \subseteq W \implies W \in \mathcal{F}$, so $\varepsilon(x) , \varepsilon(y) \subseteq \mathcal{F}$, which means that $x,y \in \lim \mathcal{F}$ and then $x,y \in \lim S$ . In other words, we have found a net $S$ with $| \lim S | > 1$ .
